# Return a simple COUNT of total days in the current calendar month

Tags: looker-studio

As per title - I literally just want to return a COUNT of the number of days in the current month i.e. for June it would be 30 and for July, 31.

I've tried `COUNT(DAY OF THE MONTH)` and the same with `DAY INDEX`.

I've no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your use case is, but to get an estimate for the month of the report, I had to do a CASE for the month, where I put the number of days in each month, and, of course, there's February messing everything up.

```
CASE
  WHEN Month Number = 1 THEN '28'
  WHEN Month Number = 3 THEN '30'
  WHEN Month Number = 5 THEN '30'
  WHEN Month Number = 8 THEN '30'
  WHEN Month Number = 10 THEN '30'  
  ELSE '31'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

This formula will remember about leap years:

```
CASE
  WHEN MONTH(Day) IN (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12) THEN 31
  WHEN MONTH(Day) IN (4, 6, 9, 11) THEN 30
  ELSE 
    CASE
      WHEN MOD(YEAR(Day), 4) = 0 AND MOD(YEAR(Day), 100) != 0 OR MOD(YEAR(Day), 400) = 0 THEN 29
      ELSE 28
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Used:

```
CASE
    WHEN Month of the Year IN ('2021-01-01', '2021-03-01,...) THEN '31'
    ... THEN '30'
    ... THEN '28'
END
```

and named the field `Days in each Month`

I then used `CAST(Days in each Month AS NUMBER)` so I could use it in the calculated field.

found the solution in [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/calculate-remaining-days-of-a-month-in-data-studio-97debe22e68d)

Answer (score -1):

I use this formula:

```
MAX(DATE_DIFF(
  DATE(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()), MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) + 1, 1),
  DATE(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()), MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()), 1)
))
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?